# NuGet app.config XDT when target project has no app.config

Tags: c#, xml, nuget

I have tried to pack a nuget-packge which has a file 'app.config.intall.xdt'. The xdt file is to support   [XML-Document-Transform (XDT)](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations#Support_for_XML-Document-Transform_(XDT)).

If a target project which is going to install the nuget-package has app.config, XDT will correctly be performed, but the problem is that if the target project has no app.config, XDT will do nothing.

Are there any ways to create app.config file if the target project does not have the file, when the XDT operation is required?

The code below shows you my xdt file 'app.config.intall.xdt', and if you want to try to install the nuget package causing the problem, run the following command in the nuget-packager console.

#### To install the nuget-package

```
install-package Experiment.Xunit -version 2.0.0-pre08
```

#### app.config.intall.xdt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"
                         xdt:Locator="Condition(_defaultNamespace:assemblyIdentity/@name='xunit.extensions')">
        <assemblyIdentity name="xunit.extensions" publicKeyToken="8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.9.0.1566" newVersion="1.9.0.1566" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you could look at adding an app.config.transform to the package as described at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations

Comment: @Rhumborl I tried it already... but, the transform supports only adding elements regardless of the existence for the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Install.ps1 or Init.ps1 hook](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal) provided by NuGet.

Create a powershell script that if app.config does not exist it creates it with default value

Another way could be (I cannot test it now) to add an app.config file with the desired value in the [content folder of nuget packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Content_Files).

I think that nuget will not overwrite the file if present in the project root.

---Update---

Nuget documentation: [Allow users to overwrite content files that already exist](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.5#Allow_users_to_overwrite_content_files_that_already_exist)

---Update 2----

I made some tests: you can use [Configuration File Transformations](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations#Configuration_File_Transformations) instead XDT to have the desired behavior

Comment: As far as I know about the install.ps1 script, after the nuget package is installed, the script is installed. Also, The way using nuget content folder would have the same problem with the installing order.

Comment: @Jin-WookChung content folder can contain the app.config with the value you would ovverride with xdt. so if no app.config files is found during nuget package installation it is copied. if app.config is found then xdt will do the work. use install.ps1 or if it called too late use init.ps1

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean. Thanks you for you answer.